# Mongo indexes question

Tags: index, mongodb

I have the following aggregation query:

```json
db.getCollection('usersongs').aggregate([
        {$match: { room: 'someObjId', status: { $in: [ "ended", "skipped" ] } } }, 
        {$group: { 
            _id: "$song", 
            timesPlayed: { $sum: 1 }, 
            scores: { $sum: { $subtract: [ "$likes", "$dislikes" ] } } 
        }}, 
        {$sort: { scores: -1 } }, 
        {$limit: 10 }
]);
```

The schema of "usersongs" has the following fields (and some more):

- room (ObjectID)
- song (ObjectID)
- status (string)
- likes (int)
- dislikes (int)

I already have an index for `room` and `status` fields but the query is still very slow (5 seconds plus), should i add more fields to this index combination for the query structure above?

I tried to added `{explain: true}` as a second parameter to the `aggregate` method but can't find anything helpful in the output (also it looks ran too fast at this mode).

```json
db.usersongs.find(
    { room: 'someObjId', status: { $in: [ "ended", "skipped" ] } }).explain(true)
```

returns [this output](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/shlomisas/o6Mzy).

I am using v3.2.4

This started after migration from single node to ReplicaSet, indexes were rebuilt from the mongodump files (BSON's) but maybe something was missed out? Maybe I need to rebuild the index?

The document has more than 7M records. This is why I created so many indexes to support different operations. I'm doing in the code (each one have his own conditions so I want to cache that to speed things up).

Why does mongo choose "room_1_song_1_status_1_duration_1" index as the winning plan? The proper index to my case is "room_1_status_1".

I tried:

```json
db.usersongs.find(
    { room: ObjectId('someId'), status: { $in: [ "ended", "skipped" ] } }
    ).hint( "room_1_status_1" )
```

...and now it's running perfectly! The problem is the that hint isn't supported with the aggregation framework. So it hasn't solved my problem yet.

Comment: The explain results show multiple candidate indexes that could support your query (and you could even remove a few unnecessary indexes that overlap). It looks like your criteria isn't very selective as the chosen query plan is an index scan and your results (`nReturned`) match 44,896 documents based on 45,183 index comparisons (`keysExamined`). Do nearly all your `usersongs` have the same room ID at the moment? A query that returns most (or all) documents from a collection won't benefit from an index.

Comment: What's the total count of documents in the collection? It looks like your match is currently close to 100% of the total (44,896 documents returned on an index scan versus 45,193 index comparisons). In this case *any* index (or even a collection scan) will be as effective for returning your results. If you consider a query that processes all documents in a collection, an index comparison and document lookup involves more work than simply iterating through all documents in the collection (via a collection scan). There is no deterministic winning plan for your current query and indexes.

Comment: Go figure, after it runs perfectly now. ;) Would you mind to write an answer?

Comment: The problem is that hint isn't support with the aggregation framework.. So it doesn't solved my problem yet.

Comment: But @Stennie gave you the proper advice: Get rid of the redundant indices. And it might help to actually narrow down the results more, and even if it is just by limiting the result's fields and/or use an (early) limit. Because in my book, less then 0.2 milliseconds/doc is not exactly slow...

Comment: Hi @MarkusWMahlberg, As far as i understood from @Stennie, the main issue is that the winner index has return `nReturn` amount that is almost the same like  `keysExamined` and this is the issue.. i can remove overlap indexes but the question is if this will help for the performance or just reduce the disk usage those indexes takes. also, the app is running on production and i'm afraid that removing some indexes will cause performance issues if i'll make a mistake.. i'm trying to find some bullet prof solution before implement that.. still thinking.. :)

Comment: What values can `status` have?

Comment: enum: ['running', 'active', 'ended', 'deleted', 'skipped']